# Efforts or plans to port gson to C++

Tags: c++, json, gson

Does anyone know if there have been any efforts or plans to create a C++ version of gson? The library is very helpful and one the easiest to use and it would be great if there was something similar for C++/

Comment: What is the difference between **j**son and **g**son?

Comment: I believe gson is a set of classes to write/read json objects. It is written by Google and hence the 'g'son.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean the google project to convert json into java objects and back?

There are c++ json libraries but from what I understand, the advantage of gson is the ability to automatically serialize objects.

The problem that makes this difficult, and impossible to do as well as in other languages is that C++ doesn't support reflection, and has basically zero run-time type info. This makes something like gson about impossible to do in a similar manner.

Take this with a grain of salt because while I do have a whole lot of C++ experience. I've never actually used gson, and thus don't really know what it is you desire.

Comment: Cool ... what's reflection if I may ask?

Comment: It's the ability for a program to inspect and compute based on metadata of it's own data structures and code.  For instance, in a language that offers reflection, I should be able to declare a class, and without any extra code specific to that class, write a function that'll print out all of the members of that class, or any class for that matter. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29